# kDrive from Infomaniak

Tags: software-installation, appimage

I am trying to install `kDrive` and related products on Ubuntu. I can download the `Appimage` file `kDrive-3.3.7.20221109`, however I do not understand how to use this to install the application. The instructions on the web site do not help, as they clearly refer to other versions of Linux. Please can I get step by step instructions?

Comment: Make it executable. Run it

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 no longer have the `libfuse2` package by default. So, you need to install it:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

As R A said in the comment, you also need to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x kDrive-3.3.7.20221109
```

Comment: Thank you both for the above responses, I have done as you both proposed and at least initially it works!